# What are the differences between you and your clone?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the last battle against Diablo, you face a clone of yourself (or of your party)

What are the key differences between you and your clone? Is it based on your stats/equipement, or is it just a mob with fixed stats that changes depending on your class?

Comment: I was *just* about to ask this!

Comment: Seems like I was faster. Yay!

Comment: To add something not known to many, your clone does not spawn if you are dead. Being dead during clonespawns is something to consider for WD players (on Inferno) as the dot skill the clone has is certain dead to any character. WD dying + getting ressed is less of an issue than your tank getting screwed. :)

Comment: The Meta tag...in a title...   >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clone has fixed stats depending on your class and your difficulty, and seems to use abilities from a pre-defined list regardless of what you have equipped - the Wizard clone, for instance, likes to use Venom Hydra and Energy Twister even if the only attack skills you have are Shock Pulse and Ray of Frost.