# Fighting shadow clones during phase 2 of Diablo

Tags: diablo-iii

I keep diying to the demonhunter clone diablo summons in Phase 2 during the final fight against the prime evil. The funny part is, that it's not diablo who kills me but myself/Diablos's shadowclone.

My question is wether or not the clone is influenced by my equipment and doing so much damage because of my own gems?

Also, do my active skills influence his abilities as well or is it a random rotation?

What is the most effective way to kill the clone? Snares don't seem to work in the fight demonhunter vs demonhunter and im usually on 2/3 of my hp going into phase 2 so the clone kills me right away.

Comment: Not sure about *fighting* the demon hunter clone (I play barbarian), but active skills don't matter; the shadow clones seem to have fixed skills, though which skills those are may change based on difficulty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between you and your clone? \[spoilerish\]](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69078/what-are-the-differences-between-you-and-your-clone-spoilerish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just burst him, I used rapid fire when fighting and I believe bola shot with the electric charge. It took like 3 to 4 shots and he was dead. I also used the turret, the spider, I did not really use and of my 4 attacks and for 1 I used the health regain so that I could heal myself to full with rapid fire.